# Is there any way to override an mvc controller action using a business class library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, overriding

Is there any way to override an mvc action from a business class library or any options for overriding an mvc action,is it possible to override from another controller or from a class library.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write the override method in the controller and call it in the action methods ? Making the class that the virtual method is in a base class ? We need more info add some example code!